# How to replace br with a text new line in a contentEditable div on pressing Enter?

Tags: javascript

All I need is to replace `<div><br></div>` or `<br>` with just a new line `\n` when a user pressing the "Enter" key.

I've got a code:

```js
divEl.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        e.preventDefault();

        const selection = document.getSelection();
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        range.deleteContents();

        const newLineNode = document.createTextNode("\n");

        range.insertNode(newLineNode);
        range.collapse();
    }
});
```

The above code works, but with some glitches. In chrome, I need to press `Enter` twice to go to a new line, in FireFox, it's enough to press one time.
I've got no idea what could be wrong. Is there a way to make this work in the right way in all modern browsers?

P.S. Don't even try to google it or search here. I've tried it many times. Nothing is working...

Comment: can you please create a demo of your problem  ?

Comment: @brk No need for this anymore. It seems, I've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
In fact, I made an omission in describing my problem. And this problem is present in all browsers...

Double-pressing is required when the cursor is placed at the end of the contentEditable div. A double `\n` must be added to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution could be to not prevent adding the `<br>` but to simply replace it.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("#container");
div.addEventListener("keydown", replaceLineBreak);
div.addEventListener("keyup", replaceLineBreak);

function replaceLineBreak(e) {
  div.querySelector("br")?.replaceWith("\n");
}
```

```css
#container {
  white-space: pre;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: #FFB;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

maybe you run this code only when `Enter` is pressed

```
if (e.key === "Enter") div.querySelector("br")?.replaceWith("\n");
```

I don't know your exact use case and how this may interfere with copy-paste, drag'n'drop, or holding a key pressed.

Or you could do a debounced

```
for (const br of div.querySelectorAll("br")) {
  br.replaceWith("\n");
}
```

If you can live with the `<br>`s being in your markup for a second or two.

Depends all on your exact use case.

Comment: An editable div is NOT that easy. Different browsers and even different versions of the same browser act differently. Some of them add `<div><br></div>`, some just `<br>`. In fireFox you can see event more, something like that: `<div>text<br></div>`.
Moreover, it's not just about replacing `br`, it's about unifying things, making it easier to handle in the future. We also need to move a cursor around and do things like that.